при попытке загрузить веб сайт в WebView пишет ERR_CASHE_MISS

и ругается на Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Context was expected

У вас какой-то хаос в коде, удалите ненужное. Зачем вы перекрываете shouldOverrideURLLoading?

Евгения, скажите пжлст, а что значит перекрываю? то есть я не даю запуск этому участку кода? как запустить эту функцию, которую я перекрыл? Этот метод shouldOverrideURLLoading надо вынести из OnCreate? или что значит перекрыть? Если вынести за OnCreate, то там не обьявлен binding и shouldOverrideURLLoading  уже не будет работать

Изучите как это правильно делается: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview

Евгения, я дополнил свой пост - и там новая ошибка - я сделал все как по инструкции, которую Вы скинули. Подскажи пж в чем проблема

просит тип WebView изменить, но как?

я жен верно вместо activityContext пишу binding.WebView ?

Не все по инструкции, там никакого binding не упоминалось даже. Выкиньте весь старый код и пишите заново по инструкции. Binding - это отдельная тема в Андроид разработке, не зная основ не стоит туда даже заглядывать.

НАПИСАЛ ТАК val myWebView = WebView(R.id.WebView)
setContentView(myWebView) и та же ошибка: Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Context was expected

Написаол без binding, Создав в OnCREATE такой код:  val myWebView = WebView(R.id.WebView)
setContentView(myWebView)
 myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.ya.ru") 

все равно пишет- Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Context was expected

Заработало когда вот так написал:


package com.example.spektr

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.spektr.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  //  private   ActivityMainBinding binding;
  //val   URL: String


   private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
   // var  URL = "https://spektr-ekb.ru";
  // val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.WebView)
   // myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            //  val myWebView = WebView(R.id.WebView)
       // setContentView(myWebView)

       // myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.ya.ru")

       binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
//View view
     //   val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
/*
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
*/
              val myWebView: WebView = binding.WebView
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://spektr-ekb.ru")








   }


}



